# Valid Azure Blob Metadata Identifiers

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I've been trying to add metadata on an .mp4 video that is stored on an Azure Blob. I want to add opengraph tags and when I try and enter them in, I get a message that says, "The name: 'og:type' should be a valid C# identifier." I'm not a C# developer and haven't been able to find documentation that shows valid C# identifiers for meta tags. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Edit: I must've misunderstood the purpose of the Metadata section as I thought it would add HTML meta tags to the document on the video's page. Do you know if this is possible? For example I want to share the link to this video on a social media site and would like to try and get this video to be able to play inline or have at least an image preview when sharing the link to the video

[image: Azure Error Screenshot]

Comment: A "valid identifier" in C# is for example the name of a variable, which as one of a few rules "must start with a letter or underscore", i.e it must not start with a digit like "5": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names

Answer (score 1):

Adding metadata to existing Azure blobs will only work if you give **valid input.**

Please **note** that:

> **Beginning with version 2009-09-19, metadata names must adhere to the naming rules for C# identifiers**

As mentioned by [@Stefan Wuebbe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4489263/stefan-wuebbe) , you can find C# naming rules and conventions by following **this** document:

[**C# identifier names | Microsoft Docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names)

***I tried in my environment and got the same error if I use colon (:) in the middle of metadata name.***

[image]

**To resolve the error**, make use of ***underscore (_)*** instead of ***colon (:)*** like below:

[image]

To know more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[Setting and retrieving properties and metadata for Blob service resources (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Setting-and-Retrieving-Properties-and-Metadata-for-Blob-Resources#Subheading1)

Comment: I must've misunderstood the purpose of the Metadata section as I thought it would add HTML meta tags to the document on the video's page. Do you know if this is possible? For example I want to share the link to this video on a social media site and would like to try and get this video to be able to play inline or have at least an image preview when sharing the link to the video.